# Save multiple arrays in one array in wordpress admin

Tags: database, wordpress, themes

I am trying to create a multidimensional array in the WordPress database from the options pages. I have the form tag

```
<form action="options.php" post="post">
```

I get the options by

```
<?php settings_fields( 'theme_styles' ); ?>
<?php $options = get_option( 'theme_styles_options' ); ?>
```

I have a field

```
<input type="text" id="theme_styles_options[option_name]" name="theme_styles_options[option_name]" class="regular-text" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options[option_name] ); ?> />
```

I would like to be able to have this field multiple times but under different arrays e.g.

```
array(
  'first_array' => array(
    'option_name' => 'value1'
  )
  'second_array' => array(
    'option_name' => 'value2'
  )
)
```

I know at the moment it my current code saves as

```
array(
  'option_name' => 'value1'
)
```

How do I set my field to send the value to the options.php page to be saved as a multidimensional array? Also, if someone knows how to save it, how do I retrieve it from the field in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you save - with `add_option` or `update_option` - just merge you existing arrays into an other big one. Both there functions accept arrays.

Get a option back out of the database with `get_option`

More details -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API